# Qt signal and slot mixed with c++ callbacks

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, callback, signals-slots

I have a program that currently implemented using Qt framework with signal & slot mechanism. However due to some requirements, I need to split the program in two parts: 1-The library, which is plain c++, independent from third-party softwares and 2-The GUI application, which linked to the library (1) and can have dependencies to Qt.

That means I need to refactor some classes from the original signal/slot approach and implement c++ observer pattern / listener instead.

So my question is, how can my GUI (Qt part) communicate with the rewritten library, is there a way to connect a signal/slot with its equivalent C++ callbacks.

For example if I have the following class Example.h:

```
signal:

void data_sent( bool start_timer = true );
```

Now it's gonna be moved to ExampleListener.h:

```
void on_data_sent( bool start_timer = true );
```

And in the GUI part I had :

```
connect( m_state, SIGNAL( data_sent ), this, SLOT( update( ) ) );
```

Is it valid to have something like this:

```
connect( m_state, SIGNAL( on_data_sent( ) ), this, SLOT( update( ) ) );
```

So in short, is a mix between signal / slot and traditional C++ callbacks works ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax). The "classic" approach uses special preprocessor, so it's not an option.

Comment: The GUI application links the "out of dependencies" library because of this you can write a layer in the GUI application as an interface between the application and the library. This layer can receive Qt signals and works with the library without constraints